# Installing Georeferencer Plug-in to QGIS on OS X

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, osx

I'm trying to install the Georeferencer plug-in in QGis 1.7.0 on Mac OS X (10.5.8).
However the plug-in doesn't show up in the list. I have used "enable 3rd parties directory" and I have checked "manage plug-ins", it's not installed yet.

I believe that I can't install a newer version of QGis on OS X 10.5.8.

If there's no way to install the plug-in, are there other ways to georeference raster imagery?