# QGIS "Raster->Georeference" menu item not showing up

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, gui

I am using QGIS 2.12.0 Lyon. I have installed a plug-in called "Georeferencer GDAL" and the version of that plug-in is 3.1.9 . [I am working on a Mac which is running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.]

I am trying to follow tutorials on georeferencing. A critical step is "Click on Raster -> Georeference".

In my Raster menu, no item named "Georeference" appears. But the Plug-in Manager assures me that the plug-in "Georeferencer GDAL" is in fact installed. How can I get it to appear in the Raster menu, or in some other way that makes it accessible for my use?

Comment: potentially related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/install-georeferencer-plug-in-qgis-1-7-0-os-x?rq=1

Comment: @AndreJ  That was the solution -- to make sure the box next to the listed plug-in was "checked". For other beginners, I will add these details: (1) the checkmark in the square next to each plug-in is VERY, very faint on some screens; (2) clicking the square box did not add a checkmark, but double-clicking the name of the plug-in did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin is installed by default, but for strange reasons it might get deactivated in the plugin manager.

Checking the square left to the plugin name, or double-click on the plugin name  will enable the plugin permanently.